# Creating dynamic WebWorker ( Refused to execute script from because its MIME type ('text/html') )

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, web-worker

Have problem with webworker.
Have this line for creating:

`public dbWorker = new Worker(new URL('./workers/db-worker.worker', import.meta.url), { type: 'module' });`

And get an error:

```
Refused to execute script from 'https://...worker.js' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.
```

Seems need to add type `text/javascript` but I'm not sure.
Tried something like this, without successful:

```
// content = './workers/db-worker.worker';

// worker_url = URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([this.content], { type: "text/javascript" }));

// dbWorker = new Worker(this.worker_url, { type: 'module' });
```

Comment: Sounds more like you are reaching a 404 or other error page. What does `console.log(new URL('./workers/db-worker.worker', import.meta.url))` outputs there? Is it the expected URL?

Comment: @Kaiido yeah, seems, you're right. I have a pathname: "/services/center/2412f5dddb633f73e20f.ts" instead "/real/..."